# TypeScript/JavaScript Date.parse is not returning NaN when it should

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime, parsing

I'm seeing this odd behavior in both Chrome and Edge:

[image: javascript date.parse is not returning NaN when it should]

Why would `Date.parse("DM Test 2 (Primary)")` return `981003600000`?

If I try it with just `2` it returns the same value, and if I strip away one or both of the parens, it returns `NaN`.  I'm not able to repro in any fiddles either, it returns `NaN` as I would expect.  Please help me understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would `Date.parse("DM Test 2 (Primary)")` return `981003600000`?

It doesn't, cross-browser, and the specification doesn't dictate that it should. It looks like a V8 thing (the JavaScript engine in Chromium-based browsers and Node.js), and quite possibly a bug.

[`Date.parse`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse) and other date string parsing such as `new Date` are allowed to fall back on implementation-specific behavior, which is completely undefined. From the spec:

> ...If the String does not conform to [[the Date Time String Format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format)
> ] **the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.**

*(my emphasis)*

That said, it's pretty wild if V8 is disregarding other content in the string and just parsing the `"2"`.

Based on the value it's returning, it seems to be treating the `"2"` as the month in the fallback (American-centric) form `"MM/DD/YYYY"` and assuming 2001 for the year, given you get the same value (midnight on the 1st of Februrary local time) as you would for `"02/01/2001"` and `"02/01"` and `"2/1"`. But that's just inference.

```js
const values = [
    "DM Test 2 (Primary)",
    "2",
    "02/01",
    "2/1",
];
for (const value of values) {
    // `Date.parse` and `new Date` (when you pass just one argument and it's a string) use the same parsing
    console.log(`"${value}" => ${new Date(value).toLocaleString()}`);
}
const first = Date.parse(values[0]);
const same = values.every((value) => Date.parse(value) === first);
console.log(`All the same? ${same ? "Yes" : "No"}`);
```

Comment: So... why does V8 parse `"2"` as `""2001-02-01T00:00:00""`...? If it's in the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format), I must've missed it...

Comment: @caTS - It's in the spec that an implementation is **allowed** to do that, because the string isn't in the one defined format in the spec. It's not required to by the spec, and neither SpiderMonkey (in Firefox) nor JavaScriptCore (in Safari) do it.